# How can I generate a text list of users from a windows local user group

Tags: windows, local-groups

I am on Windows Server 2012, but I believe this applies to other windows versions.

Under Control Panel -> Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups, I can right click a group and view properties to see a list of the group members. However copy and paste does not work for this list. I want to list these users in a spreadsheet. How can I generate a text list of users for a local user group?

Comment: would running `net localgroup administrators > list.txt` do?  Change the group name as required.  If you need to dump all the users of all the groups that would be doable but might require a script.  E.g. VBS, Powershell.

Comment: Here is a Powershell example to list all users in each group - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-local-groups-and-f64e63d1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the command line answer:

> net localgroup xxx

which lists the properties for the local group with name xxx